# Is it possible to get the number of javac's errors?

Tags: bash, javac

I would want to write a Bash script which executes some operations after a `javac`, depending on the presence or not of compilation errors.

In fact, if there is at least one error, these operations will not be executed. Otherwise, they will.

I tried to do something like that but it didn't work :

```
javac_return=`javac [...] -d ../class`
if [ javac_return -eq 0 ]
then
# operations
fi
```

Comment: `javac ... || { echo "failed to compile" >&2; exit; }` will exit your script with an error if `javac` fails. Is that what you want?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

for the value of a bash variable you have to use `$`.  however, the status code is not returned as the output.

you can do, however

```
if javac [...] -d ../class;
then
# next command
else
# error handling
fi
```

or, with the command chaining idiom

```
command && next_command_if_succeeded || or_if_failed
```

Comment: Did you forget `$` before `status` (ie. : `if [ $status ]`) ?

Comment: funny, that was exactly my comment!